# Using BigQuery with R for Analyzing Data

Tags: r, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I plan to use Google BigQuery (please feel free to suggest non Amazon non Azure services including by Google ) to do the following-
a) Analyze using R specifically for data mining, dashboards and text mining.

Both R and Google platforms are a fixed given.

My question is how and where do I find how to use R with Google Big Query. I read the RCurl documentation but got a bit flummoxed. Do you have a single use case for simple tasks that can be done with R and Google BigQuery.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

R has a new BigQuery client: https://github.com/hadley/bigrquery.

(previous answer "google-bigquery-r-client" doesn't exist anymore)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is actual or not, but
You can use BigQuery over JDBC too with RJDBC.
Check this project for the BigQuery JDBC driver:
https://code.google.com/p/starschema-bigquery-jdbc/

You can even use the Query Transformation Engine which converts the usual SQL92 queries into bigquery compatible. Hopefully it solves your problem.

More info about R and JDBC:
http://www.rforge.net/RJDBC/

Answer (score 0):

You can check r client for Bigquery.
http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-r-client/

You can execute bigquery and save the results in R dataframe using the google-bigquery-r-client.

Comment: Unfortunately, the BigQuery R client shown there is for BigQuery version 1, which has been turned down. There was some work on a BigQuery V2 client, but it was never checked into CRAN. I'll investigate the status and get back to you.

Comment: I'm the person Jordan asked -- and unfortunately, there's still no ETA on the V2 client. "Soon" is the best I can offer right now.